# Text decoration is trimmed off with standalone package

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, standalone, decorations, crop

I am decorating an arc with text as shown in this MWE using the `standalone` class:

```
\documentclass[10pt,class=article]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % \path (-6, 0) grid (6, 6); % words on top of arc are trimmed off
  \path [decorate,decoration={text along path, text align={align=fit to path stretching spaces}, text={|\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont|Aut inveniam viam aut faciam}}] (-5, 0) arc (180:0:5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The text decoration is trimmed off at the top of the arc.

The results do not change with either the `crop` or the `preview` option of `standalone`.

By including an undrawn grid (see commented line in MWE), I can get the full graphic but then I need to run the PDF through `pdfcrop` to get a tight bounding box.

Is there a more elegant solution using `standalone` and perhaps something else?

I would rather use the `tikzpicture` than a PDF in my main document.

Comment: Thanks @Gonzalo Medina. But how did you come by the number 15pt? Was it by eyeballing the output? I was hoping for something more automatic, but this solution is both simple and attractive.

Comment: yes, it was trial/error. In fact, it has to be a larger value (see my answer below).

Comment: I've updated my answer with some new options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the `border` key to add some space at the top; this will also allow you to suppress some white space from the bottom (if desired):

```
\documentclass[10pt,class=article,border={0 -60pt 0pt 20pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    %\path (-6, 0) grid (6, 6); % words on top of arc are trimmed off
  \path [decorate,decoration={text along path, text align={align=fit to path stretching spaces}, text={|\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont|Aut inveniam viam aut faciam}}] (-5, 0) arc (180:0:5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Changing the values for the arc path also helps:

```
\documentclass[10pt,class=article]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path, text align={align=fit to path stretching spaces}, text={|\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont|Aut inveniam viam aut faciam}}] (-5, 0) arc (160:20:5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Combining both options, one gets:

```
\documentclass[10pt,class=article,border={8pt -10pt 8pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path [decorate,decoration={text along path, text align={align=fit to path stretching spaces}, text={|\fontsize{40}{48}\selectfont|Aut inveniam viam aut faciam}}] (-5, 0) arc (160:20:5cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After playing around with your solution, I have found a possible error in the `standalone` manual. It reads `border={ length (left) length (right) length (bottom)
length (top) }` when in fact, it should be `border={ length (left) length (bottom) length (right)
length (top) }`. Perhaps the author would care to confirm. Thanks.