# Bounding box and umlaut issue in text decoration

Tags: tikz-pgf, unicode, input-encodings, decorations, bounding-box

[image]

In the above Ti*k*Z picture, how can I

- extend the bounding box to include the text decoration without manual tinkering (the only solution I was able to find is fiddle with the `border` or `margin` class options, see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/114661/62340))?
- avoid the error `Package inputenc Error: Unicode char` from the sharp s "ß" on line 24?

**Code**

```
\documentclass[tikz,svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\tikzset{
    entity/.style={fill=#1!70,text=white},
    action/.style={->,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=2pt,text along path,text align=center,text={|\scriptsize|#1}}}}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Entities
    \node[entity=DarkGreen] (A) {A};

    \node[entity=DarkBlue,right=2 of A] (B) {B};

    % Actions
    \draw[action=schließen] (A) to [bend left]  (B);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops.  I guess I should have said it is related only insofar as the questioner, not the content `:^)` I will delete my comment so as not to confuse.

Comment: I am not sure there is a general solution of detecting the real bounding box, but for the unicode  question `action=schlie{ß}en` works.

Comment: For the bounding box issue try using the `text effects along path` decoration: `decoration={raise=2pt, text effects along path, text align=center, text={#1}, text effects/.cd, text along path}`

Comment: @MarkWibrow Can this be combined with changing the font size?

Comment: @Casimir Yep, you can use the `/pgf/decoration/text effects/every character` style. There are various shorthands for this described in the manual p.596 - 603 (for version 3.0.1a)

Comment: To change the size of the decoration, this works: `text effects={characters={font=\scriptsize}}`

Answer (score 2):

This adds an invisible line above the decorations.  If you make the line visible, you will see that the bounding box is slightly larger than needed.

I played around with all the suggestions regarding `\scriptsize` and concluded that the OP solution is best.

```
\documentclass[tikz,svgnames]{standalone}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning,decorations.text,calc}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\tikzset{
    entity/.style={fill=#1!70,text=white},
    action/.style={->,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=2pt,text along path,
      text align=center,text={|\scriptsize|#1}
}}}}

\newlength{\mybuffer}
\sbox0{\scriptsize\strut}
\setlength{\mybuffer}{\dimexpr 2pt+\ht0+\dp0}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Entities
    \node[entity=DarkGreen] (A) {A};

    \node[entity=DarkBlue,right=2 of A] (B) {B};

    % Actions
    \draw[action={schlie{ß}en}] (A) to [bend left]  (B);
    \path ($(A)+(0pt,\mybuffer)$) to [bend left] ($(B)+(0pt,\mybuffer)$);
    %\draw[red] ($(A)+(0pt,\mybuffer)$) to [bend left] ($(B)+(0pt,\mybuffer)$);
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]